# Cancan - new form fails when user restricted to certain sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have users

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                  :remember_me, :site_id, :role_name

  belongs_to :site

end
```

sites

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_one :front_page_campaign
end
```

and front_page_campaigns

```
class FrontPageCampaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
end
```

I'm using cancan to restrict access, so users can only manage front_page_campaigns for their own site:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    case user.role_name

    when "super_admin"
      # can do everything
      can :manage, :all

    when "editor"
      # can edit content for their site
      can [:create, :read, :update], FrontPageCampaign, site_id: user.site_id

    end
  end
end
```

This works perfectly for users with role_name `super_admin` and also for `editor` on show and edit on `front_page_campaigns`.  But when an `editor` tries to create a new front_page_campaign, I get a cancan forbidden notice

```
You are not authorized to access this page.
```

The standard form offers a dropdown box of all sites, and I guess I need to restrict this to just the user's own site.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your authorization issue is solved by adding:

```
can :new, FrontPageCampaign
```

to the editor section of cancan ability init. 
To set site_id on the new and create object you can set up a before_filter:

```
# FrontPageCampaignsController
before_filter :set_site_id, :only => [:new, :create]

protected

def set_site_id
  @resource.site_id = current_user.site_id if current_user && current_user.role_name == 'editor'
end
```

you gotta make sure this fires after the resource is created but before can can authorization.

In your form (if you use the same for superadmin and editor) make the site dropdown selection readonly or hidden if `current_user.role_name == 'editor'`.

Note that if someone tampers with the form and sends an alien site_id as editor, it will be corrected by the before filter, which is not nice. If you take if out and have `:only => :new` then they will get authorization error by cancan. If you are super pedant, you should instead get a valid response with validation error. You can achieve this by 1) applying the before_filter only to new and 2) say in ability init

```
when "editor"
  # can edit content for their site
  can [:read, :update], FrontPageCampaign, site_id: user.site_id
  can [:create, :new], FrontPageCampaign
end
```

and 3) add site owner checking to model validation. This is my preferred way, keeping authorization errors for illegal access of existing resources.

hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer -really useful.  I thought `:create` was aliased to include `:new`, but it's the other way round!